# Returning multiple values from HQL query

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have the following HQL query:

```
SELECT ita.invoiceType, ita.agreementNumber, itr.ruleCategory 
FROM InvoiceTypeAgreements ita, InvoiceTypeRules itr 
WHERE ita.invoiceType = itr.invoiceType 
AND ita.agreementNumber IN (?1) 
AND itr.ruleCategory IN (?2)
```

I'm using `query.getResultList()` to get the values back from this. I assume it is returning an `ArrayList<String[]>` but whenever I try to access the `String[]`'s in the `ArrayList<String[]>` I get this error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.ejb.EJBException:
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
```

Is an `ArrayList<String[]>` not what the HQL query is returning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the error message, you get `List<Object[]>` and not of String. The resulting values are not necessarily strings (perhaps they are in your example, but generally they aren't).

Comment: I see. It needs to be an array of objects and then I need to cast each individual object a String. It works now. Thanks.